# rsync syncing more than it should

Tags: rsync

I have the following rsync set up, which is supposed to sync CDR files created during the past day.

```
rsync -av root@vpsrv:'$(find /home/cdrs/*.cdr -type f -ctime -1)' /home/cdrs
```

However, if no files are found, then this command will sync the entire `/root` directory for some reason. I've even tried to prevent this by adding `include=` filter:

```
rsync -av --include="*.cdr" root@vpsrv:'$(find /home/cdrs/*.cdr -type f -ctime -1)' /home/cdrs
```

Or even grepping for *.cdr:

```
rsync -av --include="*.cdr" root@vpsrv:'$(find /home/cdrs/*.cdr -type f -ctime -1 | grep *.cdr)' /home/cdrs
```

but no luck. Do you have any ideas?

Comment: What's wrong with syncing older *.cdr files?

Comment: We have an SQL loader on the other side, which moves CDRs to a different directory after loading them. If I keep syncing older files, the SQL loader will attempt to load them every time. Of course, if you have a better alternative, I'm open to suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
cd /home/cdrs && find /home/cdrs/*.cdr -type f -ctime -1 | rsync -av --files-from=- (source) (target)
```

The important bit is the '--files-from=-', which expects the list of files to be transferred from STDIN. It expects the filenames relative to the source-folder - that explains the 'cd /home/cdrs'...